# Compilation error when using SetThreadExecutionState

Tags: c++, windows-10, codeblocks

I need to keep my computer powered on for a certain amount of time. I found on MSDN how to use [`SetThreadExecutionState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208.aspx) to keep the program from pausing when the computer would fall asleep.  I am not entirely sure on what to do, because I have done everything that the article has shown me.

My C++ code goes as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> // Required for winbase.h
#include <winbase.h> // Required for SetThreadExecutionState
#include <conio.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int sec = 14400;   // Default number of seconds until shutdown (4 hr.)
string input = ""; // Input for the the time query 

int main()
{
    system("title Timed Shutdown");
    while(true)
    {
        // Method of getting user input will break once a number or default code is given.
    }
    cout << "Shutting down in " << sec << " seconds." << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<sec; i++)
    {
        cout << sec-i << " seconds remaining till timeout." << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        if(i%45==0)
            SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED); // First error on compiler. 
    } // Countdown
    // Method that checks for shutdown clearance.
    system("shutdown /s /t 60 /c \"TimedShutdown.exe\"");
    SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS); // Second error on compiler.
    cout << "System is timing out shutting down in 60 sec." << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to cancel shutdown." << endl;
    getch(); // Prevents the last line from 
    system("shutdown /a"); // Aborts timeout period. 
    return 0;
}
```

However, the compiler returns:

```
|        |=== Build: Debug in shutdown (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===
|main.cpp|In function 'int main()':
|main.cpp|error: 'SetThreadExecutionState' was not declared in this scope
|main.cpp|error: 'SetThreadExecutionState' was not declared in this scope
|        |=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===
```

Is there a way to fix this? Or am I missing something in the article?

Comment: You don't need to use `#include <winbase.h>` manually, `windows.h` does that for you. My crystal ball says your project is probably not setting [`WINVER`/`_WIN32_WINNT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt) for XP or later to enable `SetThreadExecutionState()` (assuming your dev environment has a Win32 SDK that declares it at all). Worse case, you could just declare the function in your own code.

Comment: I tried the article that you linked but it does not seem to help. It still says that it is not declared in the scope. There probably is a different way of doing it for windows 10 though.